# Working with variable JSON fields in Pentaho

Tags: json, parsing, pentaho, kettle

I'm a new user of Pentaho and I'm trying to parse a JSON in a Kettle step.

[image: Steps]

[image: JSON parsing]

I know how to parse all JSON fields that don't change, but there are some fields for which I cannot determine length because they are arrays. In the following example, look at the field "palavras_chave":

```
{
    "identificacao": "Manejo Floinga. ",
    "historico": "A técni.",
    "descricao": "A.sasasa ",
    "objetivos": "Existem. ",
    "sustentabilidade": "Co.",
    "vantagens_desvantagens": "VANTAGENS: resi",
    "custos": "INVESTIMENTOS e CUSTOS: a",
    "direitos": "Tecnologia livre. ",
    "instituicao": "Tecnologia ",
    "assistencia_manutencao_te": " ",
    "experiencia": "Existem cerca de ",
    "entraves_adocao": "ENTRAção. ",
    "condicoes_requeridas": "Aio.",
    "fornecedores": "Sódocumentlarizada.",
    "usuarios": "Produtecolementar. ",
    "programa": "Eme.",
    "avaliacao_impacto": " reidos. ",
    "transferencia_tecnologia": "públrsos.",
    "outros": "Até 1000 cs",
    "visualizacao_tecnologia": "Consu",
    "palavras_chave": [
        "Caaga",
        "uso vel",
        "padeireiros",
        "manrestal"
    ],
    "referencias": "Livro '.pdf",
    "replicabilidade": "Atéa. ",
    "fonte": "Meiro"
},
```

Another piece of code:

```
{
    "identificacao": "Manejatinga. ",
    "historico": "A técni.",
    "descricao": "A.sasasa ",
    "objetivos": "Existem. ",
    "sustentabilidade": "Co.",
    "vantagens_desvantagens": "VANNS: resi",
    "custos": "INVESTUSTOS: a",
    "direitos": "Tecnologia livre. ",
    "instituicao": "Tecnologia ",
    "assistencia_manutencao_te": " ",
    "experiencia": "Existem cerca de ",
    "entraves_adocao": "ENTRAção. ",
    "condicoes_requeridas": "Aio.",
    "fornecedores": "Sódocumeda.",
    "usuarios": "Produtentar. ",
    "programa": "Em áre.",
    "avaliacao_impacto": " reduzidos. ",
    "transferencia_tecnologia": "públicos diversos.",
    "outros": "Até 1000 cs",
    "visualizacao_tecnologia": "Cong",
    "palavras_chave": [
        "teste",
        "aaaaaaa",  
    ],
```

How can I parse input with variable length and work with this in Kettle? If I were programming in Python, I would simply interate over the array and do what I want with a loop inside a loop.

Is there any way to do this here? Is the concept wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, i was searching for a way to normalize my data( i didnt know that this was the term before ), a member called marabu from pentaho forum helped.
The way to do this is simple, we wanting to normalize the data, we should mark the option "Rownum in output" and give it a name like below. 
[The rownum option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l7XP4.png)

After that i can use the rownum field to keep the reference to each id of each json, in this way i can insert the right reference , in the relational dbms.  the step is here. [the kettle step](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RfX6p.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can do the following:

Parse the array `$.palavras_chave` in the JSON input step. It will give you a field with the comma separated array elements. Connect the step `Split fields to rows` and split this field on the commas. It will give you one row per array element in the result. I am sure there will be a better solution for your issue, but this was the quick solution I could think of.

Comment: The big problem is that i can't split fields to row since the array "palavras_chave" is not of the same size all the times. Can i deal with variable size fields?

Comment: I got your point. But, when you split the fields on the comma, it will automatically generate one row per array element. If you have 3 elements in the array, it will generate 3 rows. If you have 9 elements, it will generate 9 rows. Comma is an important player here. I just tested this on my machine and it works.

Comment: can you seend your kettle file? i would aprreciate, i'm not getting how i would make the relationship between the values of the array and their father to insert their relation on the table.